# How to export kernel functions which written in assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am working with a `PowerPC` processor and have to use `dcache` functions in my kernel module, like: `"clean_dcache_range()"`, implemented in `$KERNEL_SOURCE/arch/powerpc/kernel/misc_32.S`. this assembly file is compiled during kernel compilation (version `4.1.8`) and `misc_32.o` object file exists in kernel build directory.
However, i can't use this functions in my kernel module and the error `"implicit declaration of function"` appears when i compile the module using `gcc`.
Also, the `Module.symvers` file does not contain these functions.
Note that, the mentioned functions are declared as `_GLOBAL`.
So, what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: It also needs to be exported using `EXPORT_SYMBOL`. PS: what kernel version? I don't see that function in that file.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, i added kernel version. it is `4.1.8`. does `EXPORT_SYMBOL` work for assembly file?

Comment: Yes, there are some instances of `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in that assembly file. Note your function has been moved to `cacheflush.h` as `inline static` function in 2016 by this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit?id=affe587bacf48e328fb8d4c5ef9007b9c555b128).

Comment: @Jester Thank you. i will use your suggestions.

Comment: @Jester The `4.1.8` kernel does not support `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in assembly source. i tried to include `linux/export.h` or `asm/export.h` header in `misc_32.S` but compiler could not find that header.
Maybe, you referenced instances of `EXPORT_SYMBOL`s in newer versions, which is correct.

Comment: It supports. And you already have been told about the commit that changed it to be a static inline.